Source of quote "a little light dispels great darkness"
A well-shared quotation is "a little light dispels great darkness". I've seen this attributed to the Baal Shem Tov, the first Rebbe of Chabad, and "Our Sages".
Does anyone know the source of this?

The Alter Rebbe.

https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart,_Fifth_Treatise_on_Devotion_5.13

Dr Mizrachi is answering the famous attribution of the quote,
אילפא is showing it is older. Maybe Adam said it first? https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tehillim.92.3?lang=bi, https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.139.11?lang=bi. Shlomo? https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.2.13?lang=bi.

This is the quote I was thinking of - הַמְּעַט מִן הָאוֹר דּוֹחֶה הַרְבֵּה מִן הַחֹשֶׁךְ, which
אילפא quoted, and it's from Chovos HaLevavos. Thank you!
